# jQuery autocomplete inside tabs - clicking away after search creates orphan results window

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-tabs

I have an autocomplete textbox inside some tabs.

See here for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/fTQ26/3/

Try the following steps:

1. Type 'A' into the text box
2. Click one of the other tabs immediately after
3. Wait a couple of seconds

You should see that you end up with an orphaned autocomplete results box.

**What is the best way to ensure this does not happen?**

(I would appreciate an elegant solution if possible as the actual page that this is happening on is quite complex!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John Koerner is correct. But you also need to close autocomplete after clicking on another tab.

```
 $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
     select: function(event, ui) {
         $( "#tags" ).autocomplete('close');
     }
 });
```

Otherways if you wait in the first tab till autocomplete opens and after that go to another tab, autocomplete is still on top of content.

Updated fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/fTQ26/16/

Comment: Thanks for the answer Juris. However, I couldn't replicate the flaw you found in John's answer. With John's solution (http://jsfiddle.net/fTQ26/15/) I entered text, waited for the autocomplete suggestions to appear and then clicked on another tab and the autocomplete box disappeared as expected. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well yes @Mark Robinson. There is a bit more than I described in my example.   
1) Enter "A" in the input then immediately click outside the input (so it looses focus).  
2) After autocomplete opens click on anouther tab.  
3) Autocomplete is still opened.  

And since it is connected to elements focus there is a more elegant solution here: [http://jsfiddle.net/fTQ26/19/](http://jsfiddle.net/fTQ26/19/)

Comment: Ah, okay. I missed that subtlety. I think your solution is the most complete. Thank you for your help, Juris.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind to the open event and if the element is not visible, then close the autocomplete:

```
open: function (event, ui)
{
    if (!$(this).is(":visible"))
        $(this).autocomplete("close");                
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fTQ26/15/